# Installing Filter Drivers To An Existing Device

Tags: windows, filter, driver, device, wdk

I am learning how to write a filter driver and is trying to install one on top an existing HID driver (mouse or keyboard) for practising.  From what I understand, I should at least add an **UpperFilters** key to the hardware registry key.  Is there anything else I should do?

When I use regedit to manually add an **UpperFilters** key to my target USB mouse device, regedit says It cannot create the key.  I am suspecting regedit disallows modification to Windows provided device driver stack registry.  Is there any other methods to install my filter driver to an existing device stack?

Comment: Sounds like I need to provide my own INF file and choose HAVE DISK in the update driver wizard to use my own INF file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows 7 by default disallows modifications under the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum` hierarchy for anyone but the SYSTEM account (i.e. not even the Administrators), so adding an `UpperFilters` key to a particular device manually isn't easy. However, from within an INF it should be easy.

However, if you want to filter all mice, you should add the `UpperFilters` key to the Mouse device class -- i.e. to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96F-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}`. This should be unhindered even on Windows 7, but normally you do this through an INF as well.

When writing the INF, you can add the FLG_ADDREG_APPEND (0x00000008) flag in the [AddReg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff546320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section so that your filter will be added to any other filters on the Mouse device class.

Comment: How do I add UpperFilters to a device class through an INF?  Or, I should better say how to MODIFY the UpperFilters of the mouseclass as it already got a upper filter mouclass.sys. Is there any sample INF available for download?

Comment: Would it be some INF section that looks like: [VBoxMouse_AddReg] HKLM, System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96F-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}, UpperFilters, 0x00010000, "VBoxMouse", "mouclass" . (this is the one I found VirtualBox is using to modify the mouse class upper filter of the guest win install on top of its virtual machine)

Comment: VBoxMouse's INF looks like a good example. Use 0x00010008 flags so that your filter would be appended to the list, rather than replace it.

Answer (score 0):

This driver filters input for a particular keyboard on the system. If you want to filter keyboard inputs from all the keyboards plugged into the system, you can install this driver as a class filter below the KbdClass filter driver by adding the service name of this filter driver before the KbdClass filter in the registry at:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Class\{4D36E96B-E325-11CE-BFC1-08002BE10318}\UpperFilters
```

See this page:
https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/blob/1fe4cc42bedfccb97a5b2cc169f9e5306d41d0de/input/kbfiltr/README.md